# Animating a custom background image on a UINavigationBar

Tags: iphone, animation, ios5, uinavigationbar

Since iOS5 there seems to be plenty of ways to add a custom background image to a navigation bar. I've tried using the appearance proxy, which works very well to change the appearance of all UINavigationBars application wide, and the setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics: method for changing an individual navigation bar.

Is it possible to animate a change to the background image dynamically?
My application has two main states, and I wanted to fade the navigation bar between two colours to represent these two states. I haven't yet found a way to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to create a custom view for each of the navigation bar and show them and release them appropriately. Simple.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I can't find a way to animate the view of a UINavigationBar whilst it is on screen. Any pointers ?